# Send a Class to another page with Post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

a DIV of one page (for example page01.php) flips 180° everytime that I click a specific button. In simple words, this button add or remove a class (rotator) to the DIV (rotate 180°) every time.

When I press another button to change the page (to page02.php) I need check if the DIV in page01.php has or not this class (rotator) and if this class it is applied I need to send it to the page02.php and apply the same class to another DIV to looks the same as the page01.php.

This is the Button in jQuery:

```
$(".btn-rotate").click(function() {
    if ($("#box").hasClass("rotator")) {
        $("#box").removeClass("rotator");
    } else {
        $("#box").addClass("rotator");
    }
})
```

This is the DIV:

```
<div id="box" class="content-background bg-index">
```

This is the CSS of `Rotator`:

```
.rotator {
    transform: rotate(180 deg);
    transform - origin: center;
}
```

I Was thinking to use POST and GET of jQuery but i really don't know how to send the information.

Someone could have an idea?

Thanks!

Héctor

Comment: Hi @Hector , are you having `<div id="box" class="content-background bg-index">` on both page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use local storage,

```
$(".btn-rotate").click(function(){
    if ($("#box").hasClass("rotator")){
        localStorage.removeItem('btn');
        $("#box").removeClass("rotator");
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('btn', 'rotator');
        $("#box").addClass("rotator");
    }
})
```

and in another page check if it's rotated or no

```
    if (localStorage.getItem('btn') === 'rotator'){
        $("#box").addClass("rotator");
    } else {
        $("#box").removeClass("rotator");
    }
```

Comment: Hi Guys! I didn't know that alternative! Thank you so much. But is not working. I don't know what Im doing wrong. For now is working to save and erase the data in the localstorage (I checked in the Developer Tools and the values are saved). But when I try to get them in the Page02.php is not working. I did this: 

         $(document).ready(function() {
                 if (localStorage.getItem("btn")){
                     $("#box").addClass("rotator");
                 } 
           });
Any clue?

Comment: are you have element with id #box in page2?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the `div` with same `id` on both page page01.php and page02.php.

You can use Web Storage API to store certain values on browse for future uses as per your requirement. Here I have used `sessionStorage`. The `sessionStorage` object stores data for only one session (the data is deleted when the browser tab is closed). You can use `localStorage` property stores data with no expiration date.

On page page01.php

```
$(".btn-rotate").click(function() {
    if ($("#box").hasClass("rotator")) {
        $("#box").removeClass("rotator");
        sessionStorage.removeItem("hasClass");
    } else {
        $("#box").addClass("rotator");
        sessionStorage.setItem("hasClass", "yes");
    }
})
```

on page page02.php

```
if (sessionStorage.hasClass) {
    $("#box").addClass("rotator");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Mistake, i forgot to put "=== 'rotator'. Thank you so much guys, works like a charm! Here is the final code:

page01.php:

```
    $(".btn-rotate").click(function(){
        if ($("#box").hasClass("rotator")){
           localStorage.removeItem('rotated');
            $("#box").removeClass("rotator");
        } else {
            $("#box").addClass("rotator");
             localStorage.setItem('rotated','rotator');               
        }
    })
```

Page 02.php:

```
get_localstorage();
function get_localstorage() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("rotated") === 'rotator'){
            $("#box").addClass("rotator");
        } 
  };
```

Thanks again!!!